# jQuery fade out warning after key input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

`if(ns1 == '' && ns2 == '')` is empty than user will get this warning `Please fill in both nameserver` when user click submit button. I want to fade out the warning when user click `ns1` textbox and start typing. How could I achieve that? Help me please? Thank you.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#submitButton').click(function(){

                var rege = /^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\.)+[a-z]{2,3}\.$/i;


        var zone = $('#zone').val();
        var nama_subdomain = $('#nama_subdomain').val();
        var ns1 = $('#ns1').val();
        var ns2 = $('#ns2').val();

if(ns1 == '' && ns2 == ''){
$('#display').html('Please fill in both nameserver'); 
$("#ns1").focus();
return false;
} 

if(ns1 == ''){
$('#display').html('Please fill in nameserver 1'); 
$("#ns1").focus();
     return false; 
} 
else if(ns2 == ''){
$('#display').html('Please fill in nameserver 2'); 
$("#ns2").focus();
     return false; 
} 

var parts = ns1.split('.');
var parts2 = ns2.split('.');

if (parts.length < 3 || !rege.test(ns1)) 
{ $('#display').html('Invalid nameserver 1 format'); 
$("#ns1").focus();
return false;
}
else if (parts2.length < 3 || !rege.test(ns2)) 
{ $('#display').html('Invalid nameserver 2 format'); 
$("#ns2").focus();
return false;
}


        $('#display').html('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/UbMeQ.gif"> saving...');
            $.post('pros.php', {
                zone : zone,
                nama_subdomain : nama_subdomain,
                nameserver1 : ns1,
                nameserver2 : ns2
            },
             function(zone) {

           $('#display').html(zone);
             } 
          );


        });
    });


    </script>
```

The html:

```
    <label for="data">Nameserver 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="textInput" maxlength="255" size="30" value="" id="ns1" name="nameserver1">


            <label for="data">Nameserver 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="textInput" maxlength="255" size="30" value="" id="ns2" name="nameserver2">

    <div id="display" style="color: green;">

<button id="submitButton" value="Save" type="button"><span>Save</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a `keypress` event handler on that condition which will fade out the message and then unbind it once the user types anything.

```
if(ns1 == '' && ns2 == ''){
   $('#display').html('Please fill in both nameserver'); 
   $("#ns1").focus()
   .unbind('keypress')
   .keypress(function(){
      if(this.value != ''){
         //fade out the message
         $('#display').fadeOut();

         //unbind the keypress event we don't need it now
         $(this).unbind('keypress');
      }
   });
   return false;
}
```

Do the same for other textbox.

Comment: I just discover a problem. I do the same with other textbox and now the warning only appear once. For example I click submit with empty textbox so I get warning `Please fill in both nameserver`. After that I start typing in `ns1` and the warning fade away which is very nice but when I click submit again (got data on ns1 textbox but no data on ns2 textbox) no warning appear. I suppose to get `Please fill in nameserver 2` but no the warning just appear once. Here is the code for `ns2` empty textbox validation:

Comment: `else if(ns2 == ''){
$('#display').html('Please fill in nameserver 2'); 
$("#ns2").focus()
   .unbind('keypress')
   .keypress(function(){
      if(this.value != ''){
         //fade out the message
         $('#display').fadeOut();

         //unbind the keypress event we don't need it now
         $(this).unbind('keypress');
      }
   });
     return false; 
} ` Please help me.

Comment: You have to `fadeIn` the display message before showing it. Change this `$('#display').html('Please fill in both nameserver');` to `$('#display').html('Please fill in both nameserver').fadeIn();` at all the places.

Answer (score 0):

This should work exactly the way you described:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#submitButton').click(function(){

                var rege = /^([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*\.)+[a-z]{2,3}\.$/i;


        var zone = $('#zone').val();
        var nama_subdomain = $('#nama_subdomain').val();
        var ns1 = $('#ns1').val();
        var ns2 = $('#ns2').val();

if(ns1 == '' && ns2 == ''){
$('#display').show().html('Please fill in both nameserver'); 
$("#ns1").focus();
return false;
} 

if(ns1 == ''){
$('#display').show().html('Please fill in nameserver 1'); 
$("#ns1").focus();
     return false; 
} 
else if(ns2 == ''){
$('#display').show().html('Please fill in nameserver 2'); 
$("#ns2").focus();
     return false; 
} 

var parts = ns1.split('.');
var parts2 = ns2.split('.');

$('#ns1, #ns2').keypress(function(){
    $('#display').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: So the changes you made only this `$('#ns1, #ns2').keypress(function(){
    $('#display').fadeOut();
});` correct? Well I use it and when I click the textbox and start typing the warning won't just fade away, it still there.

Comment: Could I please see the actual webpage?

Comment: Hi there, I appreciate your help but the problem has been solved. Thanks again :)